# I'm extracting images url's from html file and add the images url's to a List<string> how can i change the order of the items in the List?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code im using to extract the urls from the html file:

```
private void test(string firstTag, string lastTag, string f)
        {
            List<string> imagesUrls = new List<string>();
            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = 0;
            int position = 0;

            string startTag = firstTag;//"http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx";
            string endTag = lastTag;//"cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa";

            startIndex = f.IndexOf(startTag);

            while (startIndex > 0)
            {

                endIndex = f.IndexOf(endTag,startIndex);
                if (endIndex == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                string t = f.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + endTag.Length);
                imagesUrls.Add(t);
                position = endIndex + endTag.Length;
                startIndex = f.IndexOf(startTag,position);
            }
            string item = imagesUrls[imagesUrls.Count - 1];
            imagesUrls.Remove(item);
            for (int i = 0; i < imagesUrls.Count; i++)
            {
                if (f == satelliteMapToRead)
                {
                    imagesUrls[i] = stringForSatelliteMapUrls + imagesUrls[i];
                }
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(imagesUrls[i], UrlsPath + "Image" + counter.ToString("D6"));
                }
                counter++;
            }
            List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(UrlsPath).ToList();
            uf.MakeGIF(files, localFilename + "weather", 80, true);
        }
```

The variable f is the html file im reading all text from.
In the in this html file the List imagesUrls contain 9 items:

The first item in the List is :

```
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309172215&ir=true
```

The second item in the List is:

```
http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309172200&ir=true
```

In the first url the date and time are: 2013 09 17 22 15  date is 2013 09 17 and time is 22:15

In the second item the date and time are: 201309172200
So its going from the last date and time url one to the first one .
And this is the order in the html file.

How can i change it in the List imagesUrls after the List is filled with the 9 items so it will be from the first one to the last one ?

EDIT**

I did this:

```
if (f == satelliteMapToRead)
            {
                sortedList =
                imagesUrls
                .OrderBy(s =>
                DateTime.ParseExact(
                System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s).Get("time"),
                "yyyyMMddHHmm",
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (f == satelliteMapToRead)
                    {
                        imagesUrls[i] = stringForSatelliteMapUrls + imagesUrls[i];
                    }
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.DownloadFile(imagesUrls[i], UrlsPath + "Image" + counter.ToString("D6"));
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
```

But after sorted the List i need to use the sorted list instead the imagesUrls list but they are not the same since imagesUrls is List

So hwo can i replace in this part of the code the sortedList with the imagesUrls List ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of the URI's like so:

```
var list = new List<String>()
{
    "http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309172215&ir=true",
    "http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309172200&ir=true",
};
```

You can parse the Query String, then the parse `time` argument as part to a `DateTime` and use that as part of an `OrderBy` in Linq:

```
var sortedList = 
list
.OrderBy(
    s =>
        DateTime.ParseExact(
            System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s).Get("time"),
            "yyyyMMddHHmm",
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Dave The problem is that after i sorted the List how can i use the variable sortedList instead the imagesUrls in the rest of the code ? Updated my question with it !

Comment: @user2760148 You can iterate over over the `sortedList` with a `foreach` statement rather than treating the list like an array.  ie `foreach( var url in sortedList ) { ... }` but you will have to construct a new list with the appended `stringForSatelliteMapUrls`